# What is the posterior expected value of Beau’s weight?

Tags: statistics

Everyone knows that giraffes are tall, but how much do they weigh? Let’s suppose that the weight of male giraffes is normally distributed with mean $1200$ kg and standard deviation $200$ kg.

Sai at the zoo and was given the task of weighing their male giraffe Beau. Now weighing a giraffe is not easy and the process produces random errors following a $N(0, 100^2)$ distribution. To compensate for the inaccuracy of the scale sai weighed Beau three times and got the following measurements:

$1250$ kg, $1300$ kg, $1350$ kg

This is a normal/normal conjugate prior pair, so we use the normal-normal update formulas.

$µ$ = Beau’s weight.

$n = 3, x = 1300$

[image]

[image]

I found this question on MIT

Comment: Is $1002$ the variance of your error or is it a typo for $100^2$?

Comment: @Henry $$100^2$$

Comment: Write the update formulas and plug in the required numbers. At least you can give it a try and show us your posterior $\mu.$

Comment: I advise the zoo to hire a mathematical consultant.

Comment: Curiously, someone else was in exactly your situation in 2014: https://www.studocu.com/en/document/victoria-university-of-wellington/financial-accounting/past-exams/exam-14-july-2014-questions/1717258/view

Comment: And someone at MIT: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/exams/MIT18_05S14_Exam2.pdf That zoo really has to lift its game.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  yes, I pick this question from MIT and try to solve and understand them. Is it wrong? I put this question here because I want to know there is a solution or not.

Comment: What's wrong is pretending you're a volunteer at a zoo, when you are really no such thing. It's also wrong to lift something from somewhere without citing your source – that's a theft of intellectual property. Other than that, no, there's nothing really wrong.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is just a situation; By the way I got my mistake,  I edited the question. Thank you